# Call function by hash of the definition rather than a dumb human-given name in python

Tags: python, hash, abstract-syntax-tree, code-inspection

I understand this is insane and non-pythonic for a number of reasons, but I'm interesting in seeing how it **could** be done in order to learn more about the language.

I have about a billion parser functions that I have given names like:

```
def parser1(x):
  do_stuff(x)

def parserN(x,y):
  do_other_stuff(x,y)
```

And I call:

```
>>> result = parser1(x)
```

This nomenclature means the code base is less than beautiful, but it works. If I write a new parser, I just increment my file, and hope I counted correctly, didn't make any typos to overwrite something existing, etc.

What I would love, however, is some way of calling them, not by a name I have given them, a name that I have to think up with my dumb human brain, but according to some machine-generated name derived from the  **contents** of the function.

Eg, my ideal would be something like:

```
parser1 = """def func(x):
  do_stuff()"""

print(hashlib.md5(parser1.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest())

>>> print(hashlib.md5(parser1.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest())
"2cb3fed66c79bc14eb442afad27651c8"

>>> result = __2cb3fed66c79bc14eb442afad27651c8(x)
```

These md5funs could be stored in a dictionary mapping to their implementation, for example, then they could be iterated over, or applied according to some logic, perhaps the logic even coming from other md5funs in the mapping.

How would I do this in python?

Bonus points would be for, not just using the md5 of the string representation of the function, but the md5 of the AST of the function so that:

```
def parser1(x):
  a = 1
  do_stuff(x) + a
```

and

```
def parser2(y):
  b = 1
  do_stuff(y) + b
```

would get the same hash, and mean I don't have to human-name the function twice.

Comment: Are you wring each parser function to a separate file?  In that case you could call each function `parser` and increment the module name when calling e.g. `module10.parser()`

Comment: Alternatively, if all the funcs are in one module, `func_name = 'parser' + '10'; getattr(module, func_name)()`

Comment: What is the use case for this?  You can already store function references in a dictionary, so it's not clear what extra functionality you have in mind here.

Comment: Do you really think that "2cb3fed66c79bc14eb442afad27651c8" is easier to memorize and type than "parser1" ???

Comment: A normal dictionary could be used to map the md5 of the function to the function itself or a string with its definition in it. If the values were the actual functions, you could call one of them with something like `md5funs['2cb3fed66c79bc14eb442afad27651c8'](x)`. It the values are definitions, you'd need to use something like [`exec()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) which can be a security risk.

Comment: Why exactly do you consider a computer given name like `2cb3fed66c79bc14eb442afad27651c8` less dumb than `meaningful_name`?

Answer (score 1):

A very crude and dirty way of doing this would be (well, this whole idea is crude and dirty)

```
import hashlib

def add_md5_to_globals(f):
    # Python names can't start with a number
    md5 = '_' + hashlib.md5(f.__code__.co_code).hexdigest()
    globals()[md5] = globals().pop(f.__name__)


def f(x):
    print(x)


add_md5_to_globals(f)

_123fdffc617d4a2514f219cdd26487a3('but why')
# but why
```

This approach requires you to:

- Still come up with names (`def f`) but they don't need to be unique. Once `add_md5_to_globals` is called, the name `'f'` has no significance and can be reused.
- Know the md5 of the function you want to call (for example, `_123fdffc617d4a2514f219cdd26487a3('but why')`).

If you don't mind using `globals()` in every call, you can return `md5` from `add_md5_to_globals` and use that to call each function:

```
latest_md5 = add_md5_to_globals(f)
globals()[latest_md5]('but why')
# but why
```

Comment: But would this account for cases like `parser1` / `parser2` where two functions differ only in local variable names?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog, yes, different variable names will lead to different md5.

Comment: OP wants the *same* hash for cases like this.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog only as bonus ;)

Comment: True, true :) however it seems that you have already solved the bonus problem since the bytecode only contains indices to a look-up table of names – my bad.